# What method should I use to prevent scrolling beyond the screen size?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular web app that uses ngx-webcam to take pictures from a user's cell phone camera. For the camera component I want it to take up the full screen like it would if you brought up your native camera on your phone. I'm currently making the camera component the size of the screen and setting it's z-index high so it shows above everything else. The problem I'm having is, because there is a web page behind the component, you can scroll down past the camera. I seem to have a few possible options... I can *ngIf all the content (that isn't the camera component) when the camera is open and toggle that. I could also possibly block scrolling on the body when the camera component is open, but from what I've read that seems frowned upon.

I just need some advice in choosing the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple file input element can do the job for you. It asks the user to take a photo or upload one.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

[Example image on IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOQ14.png)

Comment: Well I need to overlay a template over the camera preview. Correct me if I'm wrong, but an image input like what your suggesting wouldn't work, it would just open the native camera app (if chosen by the user).